# Conmutar la posición de 2 elementos de una lista

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito ayuda para resolver un intercambio de valores en un array. Tengo una lista en HTML donde el usuario deberá elegir posición y posición final. Por ejemplo, si se desea que el elemento de la posición 3 pase a ser el 5, entonces el 5 debería ocupar el lugar del 3.

Lo estoy intentando con `insertBefore()` y no hay problema para desplazar para el primer elemento (posición [3] a posicion [5]), pero al querer hacer la operación inversa no logro avanzar. ¿Quizás haya otra forma mas eficiente?

```js
function agrega() {

  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre_form").value;
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = nombre;
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(li);

function mueve() {

  let pos_final = document.getElementById("posicion_final").value - 1;
  let posicion = document.getElementById("posicion").value - 1;
  let mielemento = lista.childNodes[posicion];
  let mielemento2 = lista.childNodes[pos_final];

  lista.insertBefore(mielemento, mielemento2.nextSibling);

  lista.insertBefore(mielemento2.nextSibling, mielemento); //NO FUNCIONA

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombre_form"="Nombre"></input>
<input type="text" name="posicion" id="posicion"></input>
<input type="text" name="Posición Final" id="posicion_final"></input>
<input onclick="agrega()" type="button" id="añade" value="AGREGA"></input>
<input onclick="mueve()" type="button" id="mueve" value="MUEVE"></input>
<div id="div1">
  <ol id="lista"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: En el código de la pregunta te faltó cerrar la primera función con `}`. Asumí que era un error al copiar y pegar (igualmente en mi edición no toqué tu código salvo en indentación)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá no estás intentando mover el elemento 2, sino que estás referenciando al siguiente.

```
lista.insertBefore(mielemento2.nextSibling,mielemento);//NO FUNCIONA
```

Además, una vez que hayas movido al primero, no va a estar más en la posición inicial.
Por lo tanto, antes de mover al primer elemento, vamos a guardar cuál es el elemento que está después de ese.

```
let siguiente_a_mielemento = mielemento.nextSibling;
```

Así después vamos a poder ubicar al elemento 2 en ese posición:

```
lista.insertBefore(mielemento2, siguiente_a_mielemento);
```

Código:

```js
function agrega() {

  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre_form").value;
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = nombre;
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(li);
}

function mueve() {

  let pos_final = document.getElementById("posicion_final").value - 1;
  let posicion = document.getElementById("posicion").value - 1;
  let mielemento = lista.childNodes[posicion];
  let mielemento2 = lista.childNodes[pos_final];
  let siguiente_a_mielemento = mielemento.nextSibling;

  lista.insertBefore(mielemento, mielemento2);

  lista.insertBefore(mielemento2, siguiente_a_mielemento);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombre_form"="Nombre" placeholder="texto del nuevo elemento"></input>
<input type="text" name="posicion" id="posicion" placeholder="mover desde"></input>
<input type="text" name="Posición Final" id="posicion_final" placeholder="mover hasta"></input>
<input onclick="agrega()" type="button" id="añade" value="AGREGA"></input>
<input onclick="mueve()" type="button" id="mueve" value="MUEVE"></input>
<div id="div1">
  <ol id="lista"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por la corrección, me has aclarado el error!!